# syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: shell, syntax-error

The following script is intended to run the program "senna" on all files in a directory and write the output for each file (preserving the input file name) into another directory

```
for file in ./Data/in/*;
do
    ./senna -iobtags -usrtokens -posvbs -srl < $file > ./Data/out/$file    
done
```

On trying to execute the script, the following error arises.

```
-bash-4.0$ sh run.s
'un.s: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `
'un.s: line 1: `for file in ./Data/in/*;
```

The script has the lines of code exactly as above and there is no `. Perhaps it implies something else. Help with error resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: The error says you have a backquote at the beginning of the for loop. Where does the difference between TimeBank and Data come from?

Comment: sorry for the confusion; it's consistent now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line endings in the script are wrong. Pass it through `dos2unix` to eliminate the CRs.